# Multiple model formset factory in single view

Tags: python-3.x, web, django-models, django-forms, formset

I have multiple model formset in a single view.This is used for editing the existing data of profile and to add new data by user. When user try to edit and save the data, **data is not being saved in database.** What am i doing wrong?

**views.py**

```
def profile_edit(request,username):
    profile_edit = get_object_or_404(User,username=username)
    userprofile  = get_object_or_404(UserProfile,user__username=username)
    UserDegreeFormset = modelformset_factory(Degree,form = EditForm2,extra=1,validate_max=True,can_delete=True)
    degree = Degree.objects.filter(user__username=username)
    UserCertificateFormset = modelformset_factory(Certificate,form=EditForm4,extra=1,validate_max=True,can_delete=True)
    certificate = Certificate.objects.filter(user__username=username)
    UserSocialFormset = modelformset_factory(SocialMedia,form=EditForm5,extra=1,validate_max=True,can_delete=True)
    sociallink = SocialMedia.objects.filter(user__username=username)
    if request.user == profile_edit and request.user.is_authenticated:
        if request.method == "POST":
            form = EditForm(request.POST or None,instance=profile_edit)
            form1 = EditForm1(request.POST or None,instance=userprofile)
            form2 = UserDegreeFormset(request.POST or None,queryset= degree)
            form4 = UserCertificateFormset(request.POST or None,queryset=certificate)
            form5 = UserSocialFormset(request.POST or None, queryset=sociallink)
            if form.is_valid() and form1.is_valid() and form2.is_valid() and form4.is_valid() and form5.is_valid():
                form.save()
                form1.save()
                degs = form2.save(commit=False)
                for obj in form2.deleted_objects:
                    obj.delete()
                for deg in degs:
                    deg.user = profile_edit
                    deg.save()
                certs = form4.save(commit=False)
                for obj in form4.deleted_objects:
                    obj.delete()
                for cert in certs:
                    cert.user = profile_edit
                    cert.save()
                links = form5.save(commit=False)
                for obj in form5.deleted_objects:
                    obj.delete()
                for link in links:
                    link.user = profile_edit
                    link.save()
                return redirect('profile_edit',username=username)

        else:
            form = EditForm(instance=profile_edit)
            form1 = EditForm1(instance=userprofile)
            form2 = UserDegreeFormset(queryset=degree)
            form4 = UserCertificateFormset(queryset=certificate)
            form5 = UserSocialFormset(queryset=sociallink)
        context = {
            'form':form,
            'form1':form1,
            'form2':form2,
            'form4':form4,
            'form5':form5,
        }
        return render(request,'userprofile/profile_edit.html', context)
    else:
        raise PermissionDenied
```

**forms.py**

```
class EditForm(forms.ModelForm):
    email = forms.EmailField(label='Email Address',disabled=True)
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username','email','first_name','last_name',)


class EditForm1(forms.ModelForm):
    date_of_birth = forms.DateField(widget=forms.SelectDateWidget)
    class Meta:
        model = UserProfile
        fields = ('date_of_birth','phone_no','overall_rating','preferred_language',)

class EditForm2(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Degree
        exclude = ("user",)


class EditForm4(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Certificate
        fields = ('title','institution_name',)

class EditForm5(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = SocialMedia
        fields = ('website_name','website_link',)
```

**PS1:-** *When I'm using only one model formset , then It is working all good.*

**PS2:-** *There is no error being shown.*

Answer (score 2):

You need to customise multiple formset using prefix. Prefix set the custom id for each form.

**views.py**

```
def profile_edit(request,username):
    profile_edit = get_object_or_404(User,username=username)
    userprofile  = get_object_or_404(UserProfile,user__username=username)
    UserDegreeFormset = modelformset_factory(Degree,form = EditForm2,extra=1,validate_max=True,can_delete=True)
    degree = Degree.objects.filter(user__username=username)
    UserCertificateFormset = modelformset_factory(Certificate,form=EditForm4,extra=1,validate_max=True,can_delete=True)
    certificate = Certificate.objects.filter(user__username=username)
    UserSocialFormset = modelformset_factory(SocialMedia,form=EditForm5,extra=0,validate_max=True)
    sociallink = SocialMedia.objects.filter(user__username=username)
    if request.user == profile_edit and request.user.is_authenticated:
        if request.method == "POST":
            form = EditForm(request.POST or None,instance=profile_edit)
            form1 = EditForm1(request.POST or None,instance=userprofile)
            form2 = UserDegreeFormset(request.POST or None,prefix=str(1),queryset= degree)
            form4 = UserCertificateFormset(request.POST or None,prefix=str(2),queryset=certificate)
            form5 = UserSocialFormset(request.POST or None,prefix=str(3),queryset=sociallink)
            if form.is_valid() and form1.is_valid() and form2.is_valid() and form4.is_valid() and form5.is_valid():
                form.save()
                form1.save()
                degs = form2.save(commit=False)
                for obj in form2.deleted_objects:
                    obj.delete()
                for deg in degs:
                    deg.user = profile_edit
                    deg.save()
                certs = form4.save(commit=False)
                for obj in form4.deleted_objects:
                    obj.delete()
                for cert in certs:
                    cert.user = profile_edit
                    cert.save()
                links = form5.save(commit=False)
                for link in links:
                    link.user = profile_edit
                    link.save()
                return redirect('profile_edit',username=username)

        else:
            form = EditForm(instance=profile_edit)
            form1 = EditForm1(instance=userprofile)
            form2 = UserDegreeFormset(prefix=str(1),queryset=degree)
            form4 = UserCertificateFormset(prefix=str(2),queryset=certificate) 
            form5 = UserSocialFormset(prefix=str(3),queryset=sociallink)
        context = {
            'form':form,
            'form1':form1,
            'form2':form2,
            'form4':form4,
            'form5':form5,
        }
        return render(request,'userprofile/profile_edit.html', context)
    else:
        raise PermissionDenied
```

**Read more on official documentation of django:-**
[multiple-formsets-in-view](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/formsets/#multiple-formsets-in-view)